# Doesn't save added value into database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio (2013) I have added service-based database (Database1.mdf) in my project. I have added in it a table, and via Show Data Table added two rows. Reading data from database works as required. But there is a problem with add value to database. If I while the program is running add value to database and then press "Reading data" it's ok, the data is reading. But If I while the program is still running go to "Show Data Table" and press button "update", I get the error: "This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server verison or an unsopported database compatibility".

If I press button "update" in "SQL Server Object Explorer" and then go to "Show Data Table" and press button "update", the data is updates, but no added data. Also, after the completion of the program there isn't the added data.

Why?

I have tried to change the properties "Copy To Output Directory" from "Copy always" to "Do not Copy" or "Copy if newer". But it didn't help me. Please help me

Read data:

```
string strConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Login] FROM [UsersTable];", con);
                        con.Open();
                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                label1.Text = "Last value: " + reader.GetString(0);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (SqlException ex)
                    {
                    }
```

Add data:

```
string strConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
            using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
            {
                using (SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command2.Connection = con2;
                    command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command2.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [UsersTable] ([Login], [Password]) VALUES (@Login, @Password)";
                    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", textLogin.Text);
                    command2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", textPassword.Text);

                    try
                    {
                        con2.Open();
                        command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    catch (SqlException)
                    {
                        // error here
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        con2.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: paste your code here

Comment: remove `catch (SqlException)` from your code and report what error you get

Comment: @Igor I did it, but the program works as before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**

---

Perhaps the example isn't *clear* enough for you.

```
private void SubmitNote(string message)
{
     // Ensure parameter isn't null.
     if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
          return;

      // Our Insert Query:
      string insert = @"INSERT INTO [Notes] ([Username], [Date], [Message])
                              VALUES (@Username, @Date, @Message);";

     // Define our Connection & Command:
     using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString))
          using(SqlCommand command =  new SqlCommand(insert, connection))
          {
                // Open Connection
                connection.Open();

                // Define our Command (AddWithValue / Add Approach)
                command.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Values = User.Identity.Name;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", DateTime.Now);
                command.Parameters.Add("@Message", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = message;

                // Execute Query:
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          }
}
```

So anytime I'd like to insert a message to the database I simply call:

```
SubmitNote("What is love, baby don't hurt me.");
```

That would execute without any issues, assuming the parameter and connection are valid.  You could write an exception helper, but that is above and beyond your issue.  One of the problems your potentially having is:

- Parameter may be *Null*
- An issue within your *Command Text*
- Potential issue with your *Connection String*.

Based on the issue you mentioned, a value is *Null* which means it doesn't contain a **valid value**.  For instance if you do:

```
String message = String.Empty;
SubmitNote(message);
```

That would fail, as *message* doesn't have a value.  Hopefully this helps.

Comment: I have tried this. There is an exception:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Application.exe"

Comment: That code will work if you have a valid value for `username`, `password`, and connection string stored in your config file.

Comment: In AppConfig: `connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True"`

There is an exception on this line:

`using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))`

Values are valid.

Comment: I updated my answer, the above code does work if you have valid column / table and etc.